# Preferred design for two SOAP services as one "transaction"

Tags: java, soap, transactions, distributed-computing

I am designing a service that relies on two, or sometimes even three SOAP services for update.  The flow can for example be like this:

1. my SOAP client call customerUpdate in system A
2. my SOAP client call customerUpdate in system B

for most cases this works ok, the system will be very stable (99% uptime is the goal), but there will always be that 1%. How can I make this close to transactional.

I have been looking around for some literature or someones experience with similar designs, but with no success so far.

The problem is how I should inform the caller of my service if SOAP call 1 goes ok, but call 2 failes.

so far I see the following solutions:

- I make a error message that tells the user what happened: System A updated, but system B did not. they have to resend to update both systems.
- I make a queue for updates when it fails, and give a SOAP response that tells the user system B is offline/unresponsive but will be updated, system A is updated.

have anyone stumbled upon a tested design pattern for such cases? or perhaps someone with experience can point me in the right direction, which one of the two should be preferred? which one is easier to maintain?

I do realize this might lead a bit more to a discussion rather than to a targeted question, but I hope that is ok.

Answer (score 2):

As for your first solution this might not be generally applicable.
For example, if you have `withdraw` and `deposit`, and `deposit` fails, you must not repeat the first operation.
Anyway it leaves your caller with doing it right.

As for your second solution, all services must record failed operations. Besides the caller is left in a "lost in the middle of a transaction" state.

The general approach is to have a `transaction` controlling both operations. See [here](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=20299)
for some WS-Transaction implementations.

If you cannot have SOAP transactions, I would offer only *one* SOAP function which does the transaction handling on behalf of the caller on the server side for all affected systems, for example by using XA data sources. If you lookt at your example, it might be 
one logical operation anyway.

*Update*

If you opt for your first solution, consider adding a unique, self-made transaction ID to each SOAP message. This should provide a general means for the server side to discard duplicate messages (for example by implementing a transaction log).

Comment: I like your suggestion with handling the bundling of the transactions at server side, it is something like that I am aiming at. But the underlying services that will be bundled does not work too well in a XA data source design. I will still have cases where I call system A, then B fails, and I have no proper way to rollback A. You have a very good point in regard to "lost in the middle of transaction", so right now I am leaning toward the other option, when the re-request comes in it will have to check if a result from A is previously there, or perhaps re-update A. but still messy for caller.

Comment: I've updated my answer regarding the first solution. Be prepared that self-made transactions could be challenging.

Comment: good idea, I like the suggestion, but I am a bit concerned that it adds additional "noise" for the client of my service.